# How to get values from another controller function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having Two controllers

`Usercontroller` & `SeekerController`

Here I'm having a function in **SeekerController**

```
    public function postCreate() 
    {
       $post_values = $_POST;
       return Redirect::to('user/signing')->with('post_values',$post_values);
    }
```

And having a function in **UserController** like

```
    public function getSigning() 
    {
       print_r($post_values);exit;
    }
```

here I'm just trying to print those passed values from `postCreate` function in **SeekerController**

But it show me an error like **`Undefined variable: post_values`**

How should I retrieve those values passed from `postCreate` function..

And my **routes** like this

```
Route::controller('/user', 'UserController');
```

Can someone help me..

Thanks..

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: Actually I'm using Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using laravel 5.1, you can use newer function: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

SeekerController:

```
public function postCreate() 
{
   $post_values = $_POST; //assume you get your data
   return redirect()->action('UserController@getSigning')->with('post_values', $post_values);
}
```

After this user will be **redirect** to new action (**new request**)

And you can get your data from **session** : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#basic-usage

```
public function getSigning(Request $request) 
{
   $post_values= $request->session()->get('post_values');
   print_r($post_values);
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're flashing data to a session, so get data with [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) helper:

```
public function getSigning() 
{
   print_r(session('post_values'));
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your quick response,

I done this using `session` as you all said and it work for me well

**SeekerController**

```
    public function postCreate() 
    {
       $post_values = $_POST;
\Session::put('post_values', $post_values);
       return Redirect::to('user/signing');
    }
```

And in **UserController**

```
public function getSigning() 
{
   print_r(\Session::get('post_values'));
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need PASS the variable $post_values to UserController , like this:

> return redirect()->route('user/signing', $post_values);

2. you need GET the variable in method getSigning, like this:

> public function getSigning($post_values)
>
> {
>
> print_r($post_values);exit;
>
> }